# Error uploading video via Graph API on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-android-sdk, uploading

I am working on proof-of-concept Android app using Graph API. I am trying to upload video to album of my Facebook app.

I use this part of code to do so:

```
String dataName = new File(getRealPathFromURI(this,data.getData())).getName();
            Toast.makeText(this,dataName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            params.putString("filename", new File(getRealPathFromURI(this,data.getData())).getName());
            params.putByteArray("source",k);
            /* make the API call */
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/"+sProfile.getId()+"/videos",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                textView.setText(response.toString()+" "+k.length);
                            Log.v("Response:",response.toString());
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

Even though, this is Android equivalent to [suggested method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads#nonresumable) by Facebook and that I'm trying to upload working `.mp4` file, I get this error.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400,errorCode: 352, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.}}
```

It seems to me, there is a bug in GraphRequest.java in Android Facebook SDK, which causes filename of video to be uploaded to be set to just "source".

Here, on line 2166 and 2167 in GraphRequest.java we see:

```
public void writeBytes(String key, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        writeContentDisposition(key, key, "content/unknown");
```

And arguments of writeContentDisposition in the same file on lines 2245-2248:

```
public void writeContentDisposition(
            String name,
            String filename,
            String contentType
    )
```

Which should, in case of `params.putByteArray("source",k);` set filename to "source", with no file extention for facebook to work with.

Adding `params.putString("filename", <FILENAME>);` simply doesn't work, because that doesn't change filename wrongly assigned to `source`.

In [Graph API 2.5 video reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/video#Creating) we can read the following:

> When including a source parameter, you should include a filename with the correct extension that indicates the type of file container.

Funnily enough, in [2.6 video reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/video#Creating) there is nothing like that written there.

My questions are:

1. Is there really a bug in GraphRequest.java? Or is 2.6 video reference correct, and filename isn't important anymore?
2. If there is a bug, how can I change the class, when I'm using the API via build.gradle dependencies?
3. If there isn't a bug, what is wrong about my upload script, and how can I prevent Facebook from giving me format error response?

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems there really is a bug in Facebook Android SDK.

As a workaround, I used [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), with which I created following method:

```
void uploadVideo(String name, InputStream is, String fileName){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
    rp.put("access_token",AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
    rp.put("name",name);
    rp.put("source",is,fileName);
    client.post(this, "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            //something...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            //something...
        }
    });
}
```

And everything works as intended.